# Delphi FastReports - How to change Rows?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Delphi Tokyo, FastReports V5. I have a report that I cannot seem to get correct.  The report is showing information for 1 sales rep.  It contains two Master Data bands and 1 detail data band.  Within Delphi, the pseudo code looks like this:

```
For each sales rep in table
Get Rep ID
Filter ActiveOrders DataSource based on rep ID
Load report definition
Execute report
Export Report to PDF
Next Sales Rep
```

This works fine for a simple report, such as one that only has a single MasterData band. My report is a little more complex.  Specifically, it has two MasterData bands, which are only slightly related.  The first band works fine with the pseudo code above.  The second band is ONLY a graph.  The graph has 4 datasources, because each datasource is tied to a series (aka each datasource adds a different line to the graph).  I cannot figure out how to handle the coordination of the data.

My report looks like this.
[image]

As an example... the rep is Bob.  Bob has 6 active orders, which shows up fine in the top MasterData band, as 6 rows of data.  Of those 6 active orders, there are 3 separate companies.  I want a graph of each company (in MasterData2). Below each graph, I want detailed data about the orders for that company.  I want this to show up as

```
Graph of Company 1
  Details of Company 1
Graph of Company 2
  Details of Company 2
Graph of Company 3
  Details of Company 3
```

I can write the queries to get the correct data.  I just can't figure out HOW to coordinate the data changing.  Since the MasterData2 is a graph, I can't return the data for all 3 companies, or FastReports will try to graph all the rows.  How do I tell MasterData2 WHICH data to look at, and how do I tell it that there are more companies to graph (aka another Master/Detail) set to process?